# Springboot 2 creating swagger config

Tags: spring-boot, import, swagger, config

I want to create a swagger config on springboot 2 . I added the correct dependency in PON file. But I cant still import the needed imports .

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-bean-validators -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-bean-validators</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>20.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

[image]

UPDATE:
[image]

for info:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

Comment: this is because of implementation has changed recently (see migrating from earlier snapshots for a brief update on this). https://github.com/springfox/springfox#migrating-from-earlier-snapshot
and here is solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78026580/14828354

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add below dependency to your pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

and and navigate to

```
http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html
```

change port accordingly in url

if above doesn't work then add below config:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {    

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: still getting above error

Comment: Remove SpringFox dependency and its related configurations. these are not required now.

Answer (score 1):

try reloading the entire project then clean install, also verify that the library is downloaded.

If that didnt work try this dependency : (tested with Springboot 2.3.2)

```
        <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
              <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.0</version>-->
             </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
               <version>2.8.0</version>
           </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-bean-validators</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.0</version>
            </dependency>
```

please remember this is really old and might not be supported anymore

best solution is to work with openApi (tested with springboot 2.7):

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.11</version> 
</dependency>
```

also add this to your properties :

```
springdoc.packages-to-scan=de.xqueue.txe.api.controllers
springdoc.api-docs.enabled=true
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/swagger-ui.html
springdoc.api-docs.path=/api-docs
springdoc.swagger-ui.enabled=true
springdoc.swagger-ui.operationsSorter=method
springdoc.swagger-ui.tryItOutEnabled=true
springdoc.swagger-ui.filter=false
springdoc.swagger-ui.tagsSorter=alpha
springdoc.swagger-ui.validatorUrl=none
springdoc.swagger-ui.defaultModelRendering=model
springdoc.swagger-ui.docExpansion=full
```

http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/v3/api-docs/swagger-config

Comment: still getting above error